# sqoop-export on CentOS

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I want to use sqoop-export from Hive => MySQL
I executed below command which worked:

```
sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb --table tbl_1 --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tbl_1 --username test --password test123
```

When I execute the command on my local machine it works. But when I try it on the server it does not.

Local machine: Ubuntu 12.10 with MySQL 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2

Server: CentOS 5.6 with MySQL 5.0.95-log

Hadoop/Hive/Sqoop are of the same version.

I copied hadoop/hive/sqoop from my pc to server and both operating nicely on the server.

Creating table is operated correctly.

But why sqoop error?

Log is below.

```
 sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/honeybee --table tbl_1 --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tbl_1 --username test --password test123
Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
13/01/30 07:57:05 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
13/01/30 07:57:05 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
13/01/30 07:57:05 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
13/01/30 07:57:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `tbl_1` AS t LIMIT 1
13/01/30 07:57:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `tbl_1` AS t LIMIT 1
13/01/30 07:57:05 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /home/hadoop-1.1.1/libexec/..
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/26876fd02da2baebf0e2db4e7ddb6ddd/tbl_1.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13/01/30 07:57:07 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/26876fd02da2baebf0e2db4e7ddb6ddd/tbl_1.jar
13/01/30 07:57:07 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of tbl_1
13/01/30 07:57:08 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/01/30 07:57:08 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/01/30 07:57:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201301300430_0033
13/01/30 07:57:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/01/30 07:57:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301300430_0033_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.<init>(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat$ExportRecordWriter.<init>(ExportOutputFormat.java:95)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:77)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 26 more

13/01/30 07:57:21 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301300430_0033_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.<init>(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat$ExportRecordWriter.<init>(ExportOutputFormat.java:95)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:77)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 26 more

13/01/30 07:57:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301300430_0033_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.<init>(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat$ExportRecordWriter.<init>(ExportOutputFormat.java:95)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ExportOutputFormat.java:77)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 26 more

13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201301300430_0033
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=22142
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=4
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 28.2556 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
13/01/30 07:57:35 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
13/01/30 07:57:35 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

The problem is MySQL Remote Connection.

I used

```
sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb --table tbl_1 --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tbl_1 --username test --password test123
```

But it is wrong.

I should used hostname not localhost.

I learned one thing about sqoop through this problem.

Sqoop run MapReduce.

So Data node must be able access to MySQL on server.
(I installed MySQL on the name node.)

In addition, /etc/my.cnf

I comment out 'bind-address=127.0.0.1' & skip-networking

then it's working well.